# List of recognized trusted certificates providers in IE

Tags: security, internet-explorer, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Is there a way to get a list of trusted certificate providers in IE? I will install a certificate for our websites and I want to see the list of the trusted sites by default, where should I look to see it in IE.
I would also look for the list in other browsers (FF, Chrome).

Why do I need it - I work for a big corporation and we have internal system that issues Entrust certificates and I want to make sure they are trusted by IE and I don't see the security message that the site is not trusted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE doesn't have its own list - it uses the one built into the operating system. So if you run `certmgr.msc` you'll be able to see the trusted root CAs (of which Entrust is one).

Of course if you're in an enterprise with AD you can push your own root CA anyway.

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed. Do you know if other browsers use the same list?

Comment: No, Firefox and Chrome use their own, internal, lists.

Comment: only firefox use its own internel list as it has its own store